# Winforms control hosted in IE - Https and setting to not save encrypted content

Tags: winforms, security, internet-explorer

We have an application with a .Net WinForms control hosted in IE to handle a particular hardware interface.

We have worked past the security issues and this has worked pretty well up to now, but a new client is requiring that we run under https (not a problem), but also with the IE Advanced setting to 'Do not save encrypted pages to disk'. The control itself is already installed on the local machine, but this setting seems to interfere with the fusion container instantiating the control.

Short of switching back to ActiveX (which we have verified still works) is there anything we can do to solve this problem?  We have tried running in mixed mode (plain http for the control reference) and while that works, it causes a prompt to run the control every time the user goes to the page, and clicking 'No' will make it not work(as expected).  So from a user perspective, that's a non-starter.

Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions? Do I have a re-writing task in my future?